# How to set the entire row height twice as the others in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two tables. One with additional invisible `<td>` and one without. The problem is that the second table's rowspan is not working, the entire row just collapses. How could I get the result like in the first table without adding that unnecessary `<td>`?

HTML:

```css
.table-height td {
  height: 30px;
}

.invisible {
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <table border="2" class='table-height'>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowSpan="2">A1</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A2</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A3</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A4</td>
        <td className='invisible'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td className='invisible'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>C2</td>
        <td>C3</td>
        <td>C4</td>
        <td className='invisible'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D3</td>
        <td>D4</td>
        <td className='invisible'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</p>

<p>
  <table border="2" class='table-height'>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowSpan="2">A1</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A2</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A3</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A4</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>C2</td>
        <td>C3</td>
        <td>C4</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D3</td>
        <td>D4</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it right. I just need to set the height for `<tr>` too (same as for `</td>`)

```css
.table-height td, tr {
  height: 30px;
}

.invisible {
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <table border="2" class='table-height'>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowSpan="2">A1</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A2</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A3</td>
        <td rowSpan="2">A4</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>C2</td>
        <td>C3</td>
        <td>C4</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D3</td>
        <td>D4</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</p>
```